# Revision Control to Use in Web App Editor

Tags: web-applications, version-control

I'm creating a web-based editor for web apps. I'm exploring ideas to auto-save as someone develops a web app. Similar to Google Docs, I want the developer(s) to be able to revert anything they do. What revision control solution do you recommend? Should I use GIT and commit every five seconds after developer stops typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the idea but don't have experience with the similar problem.

However maybe the 1.st answer (marked as correct one) on this question could give you a hint: [Using a version control system as a data backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519252/using-a-version-control-system-as-a-data-backend)